# How to compare result of one request with result of seckond request in MySQL

Tags: mysql, request, compare

can you help me to prepare correct query?

I need to get `category_id` from table `category_description` where `name = :name`, and check whether is record in table `category` where `parent_id = category_id` from first query.

Table category_description:

```
|category_id| name |
--------------------
| 3         | X    |
--------------------
| 2         | Y    |
--------------------
| 1         | Z    |
--------------------
```

Table category:

```
category_id | parent_id |
-------------------------
| 3         | 2         |
-------------------------
| 2         | 1         |
-------------------------
| 1         | 0         |
-------------------------
```

So need take value from first table by name, after it I need to take value of `parent_id` from `row = category_id` from first table and check whether is row with `category_id = parent_id`

In short i need check whether category exist. If not add, if yes skip.

I do something like that:

```
 SET @v1 = (SELECT category_id FROM category_description where name =:category_name);

SET @v2 = (SELECT parent_id FROM category WHERE category_id = @v1);

SELECT COUNT(*) records FROM category_description,category 

WHERE category.category_id = @v2

AND category_description.name =:category_name
```

but it doesnt work when

```
SET @v1 = (SELECT category_id FROM category_description where name =:category_name);
```

return more than one result, and PDO doesnt support multiple queries. HELP ME PLS :(

Comment: `SELECT category_id FROM category_description cd INNER JOIN category c ON (c.parent_id = cd.category_id) WHERE c.name = :name`

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help this question.

Comment: doesnt work: "Column 'category_id' in field list is ambiguous "

Answer (score 0):

Its not completely understandable but I think you can get it with a simple join like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) records FROM category_description,category 
WHERE category.parentid = category_description.categoryid
AND category_description.name =:NAME
```

So here you will get number of rows matching with name that you have provided